# Use CSS Class in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

Instead of specifying CSS styles with highchart options such as (fontWeight, fontColor, etc), is it possible to use CSS classes for styling the different elements of a chart?

Answer (score 5):

In many cases (tooltip,labels) you can set useHTML as true, and then use CSS styles without !important or use formatter to define your own elements with CSS styles.

Example http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to use `!Important` because it's the only way to override inline `style`.
Your chart is render on some content which you have to pass it's id on `chart.rendertTo`option.
So you can match the elements by your chart container, like.

```
#container text {
    font-size: 14px !Important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/46qeH/)

Answer (score 0):

Your highcharts chart is an SVG in your html.
You need to inspect the SVG source code to know the names of the classes and then you can use them in your CSS.
You need to add !important because some default styles already exist in the SVG.

For example
You can use

```
text { 
    fill:red !important;
    font-family: "Arial" !important;
    font-size  : 12px !important;
}
```

To define default font color, family and style

or

```
.highcharts-yaxis-labels text
{
   (some css )
}
```

to define the y-axis labels style

Answer (score 0):

You can use css class name in highcharts 'chart' option but these changes will not reflect on exported chart. For example:

```
chart{
    type: 'line',
    className: 'someCss'
}
```

css:

```
.someCss{
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```